# play video with qcar and android AR application

Tags: android, video-processing, augmented-reality, qcar-sdk

I am developing an android application in which a specific video is played when the poster of a specific movie is shown infront of the camera in android, i found many AR tutorial just show 3D object when detect a pattern, i need some advice to make application that can play video with AR application using android camera and qcar SDK

Comment: I am having the same requirement. If you have found a solution pls share

Answer (score 0):

I don't know qcar, but of course you can put a SurfaceView upon an existing SurfaceView from your CameraPreview and play a video in it.

What I would do is implementing your poster-recognition logic, this will be tricky enough and then, If it works reliable, I would add another SurfaceView in which the video is played.

You will find out, that the CameraPreview surface has actually to be on top of the video surface.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are trying to play video on glsurface ,it is possible by using surface video texture ,but only ics(4.0) and above devices support surface video texture.Vuforia have a very good sample of this  [here](https://ar.qualcomm.at/support_file/download/Android/android%20supported%20devices/vuforia-videoplayback-android-1-0-1.zip),you can handle what to do for lower devices such as playing video fullscreen etc..